# "cannot determine truth value of Relational" in summation

Tags: python, sum, sympy

Trying to compute by hand a matrix determinant (I know the value is `28` and can be obtained by `m.det()`):

```
from sympy import symbols, Matrix, summation
i = symbols('i', integer=True)

m = Matrix([[3,  2, -1],
            [2, -1, -3],
            [1,  3, -2]])

D = summation(m[i,0]*m.cofactor(i,0), (i, 0, 2))
```

It raises:

```
File ... \sympy\matrices\matrices.py:140 in minor_submatrix  
    return _minor_submatrix(self, i, j)  
File ... \sympy\matrices\determinant.py:890 in _minor_submatrix  
    if i < 0:  
File ... \sympy\core\relational.py:511 in __bool__  
raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")  
    TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Pinpointing:

```
summation(m[i,0], (i, 0, 2)) # Works
summation(m.cofactor(i,0), (i, 0, 2)) # Raises the error
```

I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `m.cofactor(i,0)`, specifically the `i`. By looking at the traceback:

```
    859 def _minor_submatrix(M, i, j):
    860     """Return the submatrix obtained by removing the `i`th row
    861     and `j`th column from ``M`` (works with Pythonic negative indices).
    862 
   (...)
    883     cofactor
    884     """
--> 886     if i < 0:
    887         i += M.rows
    888     if j < 0:
```

one can guess that the arguments to `m.cofactor` must be integer numbers, not symbols. So, we need to rethink how to obtain the result you are looking for. A simple list comprehension should be enough for this case:

```
# here, the i variable takes numerical values
sum([m[i,0] * m.cofactor(i, 0) for i in range(m.shape[0])])
# out: 28
```

Comment: That's what I feared, `i` `cannot be a symbol. I'm surprised, coming from such a sophisticated library dedicated to symbolic computation.